# Anonymity with tor

Tags: anonymity

Question : If you have the gmail app on your phone (samsung) and you not signed out of the app, if you then use a VPN then access tor, does Google have your search history of tor and is your tor searches still anonymous?

Answer (score 0):

Google will have your search history if you're using Google to search: with or without signing in. If you're using not Chrome and not Google to search over Tor - it depends on Google application suite integration/wiretapping in your particular mobile device model implementation - it can have it if it's wiretapping deeply

Comment: for many Samsung devices Lineage OS is available - it's an open-source Android build, and you can have it without Google app suite. If you need GMail - use a third party IMAP/SMTP client for it

Comment: Much appreciated and will give it a try